# Fixed Navbar hidding when scrolled

Tags: html, css

[image]

There is an issue with the CSS, since I'm using a fixed navbar and should go with the page, but in this case when I scroll it simply hides a part of the nav bar like in the second image:

[image]

```css
.main_nav{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    width:100%;
    height:90px;
    background:black;
    top:0 !important;
}

.main_nav ul{
    margin-top: 17px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 90) { 
            
                   $(".main_nav").slideDown();  

      
        } else {
            
                  $(".main_nav").slideUp(); 

        }
      });
    });
</script>

<nav class="main_nav">
     <ul>
         <li><img src="../img/logo.svg" style="height:50px;" alt="" /></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: can u post ur html?

Comment: why r u using `display: none;`? could be ur problem. ;)

Comment: html would be helpful because according to your css your main_nav shouldn't be showing at all.

Comment: Display:none; is used because i use JS to show the navbar after scrolling 100px, but that is not the issue

Comment: In that case may we see your JS as well as your html?

Comment: Updated now the original

Comment: Make a fiddle of it and upload **all** code

Answer (score 1):

Here are an working example of mine: http://jsfiddle.net/L3s8x96q/

```
position:fixed; top:0; z-index:100;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then I could answer you according to the provided fiddle. First you need to add an ID to the header

```
<div style="background-color: black; width: 100%; margin: 0px; position:fixed; top:0; width:100%; z-index:100" id="header">
    <button class="button button1">SOMETHING</button>
</div>
```

In the Css add the following

```
#header {
   transition: top 0.3s;
}
```

And the javascript should be the following

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("header").style.top = "0";
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById("header").style.top = "-50px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

[This following link could be useful](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_hide_scroll)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, and this is just a guess without a working example, it's a strange interaction with display none. If you're going for a slide down effect, you could use translate Y to hide and show it instead.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if(window.scrollY > 100) {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.add('scroll')
  } else {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.remove('scroll')
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 150vh;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, green);
}
nav {
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  transform: translatey(-90px);
  transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.scroll {
  transform: translatey(0px);
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
```

You have to full page the snippet to see the nav, or you can just open this [codepen](https://codepen.io/joeybreithaupt/pen/WYBBwa) with the exact same code.